# Why are the instrument panel lights too dim when lights are off?

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, lights, suburban, instrument-cluster

My 2007 Suburban LTZ has instrument panel lights that are too dim when the lights are off. I cannot even see the speedometer when the sun is out unless I turn the lights on. When the lights are set to 'Auto', no head lights are on and there should be enough light to see most of the things in the car, the instrument panel is too dark to read the instruments except when the sun happens to shine directly on the panel, but even then the instruments near the edges where there is shadow they are too dark to read. The red lights on the ends of the needles are not on either.

The controls have no effect on the lights because they are not on. When the lights are on, the controls run them up and down, although all of the way on is not as bright as I expect them to.

All I have to do to get them on is to switch the lights from 'Auto' to 'on' and the instruments are bright enough to see as well as the red lights at the tips of the needles.

Any idea how to fix this?